# How do I redirect an user back to the page they were trying to access once they log in? (Django)

Tags: python, django

So currently I'm using @login_required to block certain pages from users and redirect them, telling them they need to log in. but what I can't understand is how do I "let them" go to the page they were trying to go to once they log in. Currently I'm just using a typical render_to_response('with a certain view') but what if i want that response to be anywhere where they were trying to access. How do i code that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @login_required will generally pass you back the redirect_field_name (default is "next") for example: /accounts/login/?next=/polls/3/. So in your login view after authenticating and logging in the user you can do something like

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect(next)
# Do whatever else you need to do here with the response object
return response
```

See the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: it says the page isn't found... at accounts/login/login/<built-in function next>. am i supposed to write that in the url conf? or

Comment: no, next should basically be a string only such as '/polls/3/'. After logging in the user, using HttpResponseRedirect(next) should redirect to /polls/3/. If you are unsure you can try import pdb; pdb.set_trace in your login view and then check the value of next. Another option would just be a simple print next. This is assuming the variable for redirect_field_name is using the default next.

Comment: hmmph.. alright. well that's whats popping up so hopefully i can trouble shoot it

Comment: what is the url when redirected to the login page? if it is something like /user/login/?next=/some/other/path/ you may also be able to do something like redirect_to = request.GET.get('next', '/'); response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to); return response . If that doesn't help you may need to include more of your code.

Comment: the /?next= is pointing toward the right page. It's just when i put the response like that it come up with come weird built in function like before. also when i tried to print next it said that the variable was referenced before it was assigned. is there something i have to do to HttpResponseRedirect(next) in order to get it as a string?

Comment: without seeing more code I'd suggest doing what I suggested in the comment above. You could do it more concisely as "return HttpResponseRedirect(request.GET.get('next', '/'))"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8617/discussion-between-steve-and-jack)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a url parameter back to your login page and use that to direct the user once they complete the login successfully.

Comment: care to elaborate? or give an example I can't gather what you mean bu just the words.

Answer (score 0):

from the [login requiered decorator docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) it says:

> By default, the path that the user should be redirected to upon
>   successful authentication is stored in a query string parameter called
>   "next".

and usually when the login is done it take to the "next" url

> Here's what django.contrib.auth.views.login does:
>
> If called via GET, it displays a login form that POSTs to the same
>   URL. More on this in a bit.
>   If called via **POST**, it tries to log the
>   user in. **If login is successful, the view redirects to the URL
>   specified in next**. If next isn't provided, it redirects to
>   settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL (which defaults to /accounts/profile/). If
>   login isn't successful, it redisplays the login form.

Comment: how to i speciff what next is? or changed what the default redirect. I've asked this before but there isn't a LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in setting.py and i don't know where to find it/add it.

Comment: you can add LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL="/your/path/" to your settings.py.